# Specifying and using a NGramTokenizer with the C# NEST client for Elastic Search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

***Updated to show a working sample***

I am trying to do a partial search on a collection of usernames in ElasticSearch.

Searching around has pointed me in the `nGram Tokenizer` direction but I am stumped at proper implementation and fail to get any results.

This is the the relevant code stripped from the project I'm working on.

I have tried different combinations and search types to no avail.

**setup.cs**

```
var client = new ElasticClient(settings.ConnectionSettings);

// (Try and) Setup the nGram tokenizer.
var indexSettings = new IndexSettings();
var custonAnalyzer = new CustomAnalyzer();

customAnalyzer.Tokenizer = "mynGram";
customAnalyzer.Filter = new List<string> { "lowercase" };

indexSettings.Analysis.Analyzers.Add("mynGram", customAnalyzer);

indexSettings.Analysis.Tokenizers.Add("mynGram", new NGramTokenizer
                                                    {
                                                        MaxGram = 10,
                                                        MinGram = 2
                                                    });

client.CreateIndex(settings.ConnectionSettings.DefaultIndex, indexSettings);

client.MapFromAttributes<Profile>();

// Create and add a new profile object.
var profile = new Profile
                  {
                      Id = "1",
                      Username = "Russell"
                  };


client.IndexAsync(profile);

// Do search for object
var s = new SearchDescriptor<Profile>().Query(t => t.Term(c => c.Username, "russ"));

var results = client.Search<Profile>(s);
```

**Profile.cs**

```
public class Profile
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(IndexAnalyzer = "mynGram")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this from [the es docs on nGram token filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/ngram-tokenizer/):

```
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "my_ngram_analyzer" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "my_ngram_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer" : {
                "my_ngram_tokenizer" : {
                    "type" : "nGram",
                    "min_gram" : "2",
                    "max_gram" : "3",
                    "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

A few things to note

1. You need to add `mynGram` to your analyzer or it won't be used. They way it works is like this. Each indexed field has an analyzer applied to it, an analyzer is **one** tokenizer followed by **zero or more** token filters. You have defined a nice nGram tokenizer (`mynGram`) to use, but you did not use it in `customAnalyzer`, it is using the `standard` tokenizer. (Basically you are just defining but never using `mynGram`.)
2. You need to tell elasticsearch to use your `customAnalyzer` in your mapping:
   `"properties": {"string_field": {"type": "string", "index_analyzer": customAnalyzer" }}`
3. You should change the `maxGram` to a bigger number (maybe 10), otherwise 4 letter searches will not behave exactly as autocomplete (or could return nothing, depends on the search-time analyzer).
4. Use the `_analyze` api endpoint to test your analyzer. Something line this should work.

   curl -XGET 'http://yourserver.com:9200?index_name/_analyze?analyzer=customAnalyzer' -d 'rlewis'

Good luck!

Comment: And as if by magic it works. I'll update the sample to show a fixed version for future reference. Thanks for the guidance.